# How to convert file object to encodable json object in flutter?

Tags: json, file, flutter, dart, encode

Im trying to map profilePicture to a File object using dart , i have the profilePicture saved as IFormFile in the c# backend..

This is the mapping function and other functions in my ManageUserModel class:

```
Map<String, dynamic>toMap() {
return { 
"profilePicture":profilePicture,
(other mappings)
}
}
List<ManageUserModel> fromJson(String jsonData) {
 // Decode json to extract a map
final data = json.decode(jsonData);
return List<ManageUserModel>.from(
  data.map((item) => ManageUserModel.fromJson(item)));
 }

String toJson(ManageUserModel data) {
// First we convert the object to a map
final jsonData = data.toMap();
// Then we encode the map as a JSON string
 return json.encode(jsonData);
 }
```

Note that profilePicture is one of the ManageUserModel attributes and is of type **File** .

When the http update request is invoked via this method:

```
 Future<String> updateUser(ManageUserModel data) async {
 final response = await client.put("$baseUrl/Users",
  headers: {"content-type": "application/json"},
  body: toJson(data),
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return "Success";
  } else {
  return "Fail";
  }
  }
```

i get this error:

E/flutter (10061): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of '_File'

Any help ?

Comment: What format do you want it to be encoded to? What are you trying to do with this map afterwards?

Comment: Json, i updated my question right now, hope its more clear. @BenKonyi

Comment: A `File` is a pretty abstract thing. Think of it as a wrapper around a file name. Presumably, you doing want to send that to the server. What you probably want to send is the contents of that file, either as binary or as a string representation. As you are putting that into a JSON object, the chances are you want a string representation, perhaps base64.

Comment: To get the contents you'll need to read the contents using `File.readAsBytes` then convert that to your chosen representation.

Comment: The thing is i have the profilePicture saved as IFormFile on the c# backend, i don't want conflicts in sending my model as it should be received as the latter type.. @RichardHeap

Comment: So doesn't that require you to send a MultipartFile?

Comment: I think it does.. im new to the flutter community but i researched and i  think its compatible , i just want  an example of sending a file from flutter to an api where the backend file type is IFormFile , no clear one out there. @RichardHeap

Comment: There are plenty of examples of sending MultipartFile. Give it a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

From the error you've provided, it looks like you're trying to map '_File' object as a json.

```
E/flutter (10061): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of '_File'
```

That won't do since [fromJson](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_driver/RenderTree/fromJson.html) can only handle [Maps](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Map-class.html). What you may want to consider is to store the file as an image URL, or as what have been previously mentioned in the comments - as base64.